# Allocate more memory to Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, memory

I have to do some tasks in **Javascript and HTML5** that need heavy amount of RAM and CPU usage. Due to low memory our tasks break.Can I **allocate more memory to some particular tab in Chrome or Firefox** or anyway to maximize it for a time frame so particular tasks can be completed or this is not possible.Anyone tried it ?.I tried playing with chrome://flags/ because application uses HTML5 Canvas but not got solution.

Comment: What do you mean with "heavy amount of RAM"? More than 2GB? More than 4? More than 16? What kind of tasks are they? Are they really needed to be executed by browser?

Comment: Suppose I have 2GB RAM in my system and 1.2GB free, if Chrome can use whole free available memory to handle the task